# Remove padding from HighCharts polar chart

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Here is a JSFiddle of what I currently have:

http://jsfiddle.net/DGwcF/

I have set both the `margin` and `spacing` to `0`, though the padding still remains around the chart itself.

How do I make the chart go all the way to the edge of the container? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set pane's size as 100%, see this:

http://jsfiddle.net/DGwcF/3/

```
 pane:{
      size: '100%',
 }
```